# Why is zoneinfo shifting DST by 2 hours instead of 1?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo, tzdata

I need to make sure that when a naive datetime is made aware the DST rules are applied correctly. What I find here is just odd to me.

Somehow zoneinfo decides to increment the DST transition for America/New_York by 2 hours instead of one. It is even shifting the time right before DST to EDT by 2 hours.

[for DST New York shifts to 3am at 2am](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2022)

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def zmake_timezone_obj(tz):
    return ZoneInfo(tz)

def zconvert_to_timezone(naive_dt, timezone_str):
    tz_obj = zmake_timezone_obj(timezone_str)
    return naive_dt.astimezone(tz_obj)


dst_start = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 2, 1)

zconverted = zconvert_to_timezone(dst_start, "America/New_York")
print(zconverted, zconverted.tzname())
zconverted_add = zconverted + timedelta(hours=1)
print(zconverted_add, zconverted_add.tzname())

print()
dst_start = datetime(2022, 3, 13, 1, 59)
zconverted = zconvert_to_timezone(dst_start, "America/New_York")
print(zconverted, zconverted.tzname())
zconverted_add = zconverted + timedelta(hours=1)
print(zconverted_add, zconverted_add.tzname())


Output:

2022-03-13 04:01:00-04:00 EDT # should be: 2022-03-13 03:01:00-04:00 EDT
2022-03-13 05:01:00-04:00 EDT # should be: 2022-03-13 04:01:00-04:00 EDT

2022-03-13 03:59:00-04:00 EDT # should be: 2022-03-13 01:59:00-05:00 EST
2022-03-13 04:59:00-04:00 EDT # should be: 2022-03-13 03:59:00-04:00 EDT
```

This is using tzdata version 2023.4 and python version 3.11.4.

What is going on here and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation for `astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

> If *self* is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system timezone.

Presumably you're running this code in a computer whose native time zone is two hours different than Eastern.  This has nothing to do with whether DST is in effect.

Also note that 2:01 is an invalid time for that date, it falls in the gap between 2:00 and 3:00 that doesn't exist.  You shouldn't expect any calculations using that time to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

With `zoneinfo`, you don't have to use the old-school `.astimezone()` style of updating time zones like you did with `pytz`. Instead, you can do the easy `.replace(tzinfo=foo)` way:

```
def alt_convert_to_tz(naive_dt: datetime, timezone_str: str) -> datetime:
    return naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=zmake_timezone_obj(timezone_str))
```

That gives you the results you want:

```py
new = alt_convert_to_tz(dst_start, 'America/New_York')
print(new, new.tzname()) # 2022-03-13 01:59:00-05:00 EST
```

Comment: if you replace `naive_dt.astimezone(tz_obj)` with `naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=tz_obj)` it is worse because then I get: 
`
2022-03-13 02:01:00-05:00 EST
2022-03-13 03:01:00-04:00 EDT

2022-03-13 01:59:00-05:00 EST
2022-03-13 02:59:00-05:00 EST
`

which contains non-existent datetimes and doesn't handle the arithmetic correctly.

Comment: @Stryder garbage in, garbage out.  It doesn't make sense because you're starting with a time that doesn't exist.  `2:01` isn't valid, it falls in the gap.

Comment: This is misleading. **replace** does not **convert**. Besides, there is nothing "old-school" about `astimezone`. It is the standard method for vanilla Python datetime objects to convert between time zones. It has the caveat though that it works with naive datetime objects as well, which makes assumptions, which in turn might confuse users. The design choice is debatable, but not old-school IMHO ;-)